# Purge a resource from referer VARNISH

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

I'm trying to PURGE a HTML page if a css file is not in the varnish cache anymore. This is what I'm doing :

```
if (beresp.status == 404 && req.url ~ "\.css$") {
    ban("obj.http.x-url ~ "+ req.http.referer);
}
```

If I've got a 404 on a CSS file, I would like to ban the referer. The problem is that "req.http.referer" has "http://" in front of the URL. So, it doesn't work. (It works without the "http://".

I tried :

```
ban(req.http.referer);
```

but doesn't work.

Any idea please on how to remove the "http://" or how to do that job in a different way ?
Thanks.

**EDIT**
Find solution to remove the "http://":

```
ban("obj.http.x-url ~ "+ regsub(req.http.referer, "^http://", ""));
```

Thank you ;)